# SQL group dates as week date

Tags: sql, date

I have a table which contains func_id  and date in format like (07.06.14 ). I am trying to create a function that returns the number of dates that is the week day of a date (07.06.14 ) and the func_id will equals the func_id that I will write. For example:

My table: 
         func_id   11 / date = 07.06.14

That will return 1 from 0. (Saturday code = 0);

I tried:

```
 function Get_weekday($data){
$dat = explode(".",$data);
$date = date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, $dat[0]  , $dat[1], $dat[2]));
if($date == "Monday"){return 4;}
if($date == "Tuesday"){return 3;}
if($date == "Wednesday"){return 2;}
if($date == "Thursday"){return 1;}
if($date == "Friday"){return 0;}
if($date == "Saturday"){return 0;}
if($date == "Sunday"){return 0;}
}
function count_per_date($func_id,$day){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(date) as data,date FROM entregas WHERE func_id = '$func_id' GROUP BY date");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
 //That part I dont really know what to do
}}
```

Sorry for my english, I dont speak very well ):

Comment: Which database/ what sql dialect are you using? In most cases there is predefined function which does exactly the thing you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for DAYOFWEEK

Example

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK('2007-02-03');
```

Further info : [DAYOFWEEK documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)